# How to search for elements and change the array? Angular

Tags: angular, search, filtering

I need your help. I have a service called `articleService` and `home.component`. In `home.component` I try to display all articles. The fact is that I try to filter by article: enter text into the input and I was shown articles that have a similar title (`title`) or have similar content (`summary`). I have no errors in this code, but it does not work at all when I enter text in the input. Please tell me how to do a search and the items are displayed in order, the one-match article in the title is higher than the one-match article in the description. Thank you very much

home.component.ts

```
import {ArticleModel} from "../../model/articleModel";
import {FormControl, FormGroup} from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
   selector: 'app-home',
   templateUrl: './home.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

   articles: ArticleModel[];
   article = new FormControl('');

   searchArticlesForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
     article: this.article
   })

   constructor(private articleService: ArticleService) { }

   ngOnInit(): void {
     this.articleService.getArticles().subscribe(value => this.articles = value);
   }

   searchArticle() {
    this.articleService.findArticlesByNameAndContent(this.searchArticlesForm.value, this.searchArticlesForm.value)
   .subscribe(value => this.articles = value);
   }
}
```

home.component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="searchArticlesForm">
   <input type="text" formControlName="article" (change)="searchArticle()">
</form>
<div *ngFor="let article of articles" class="different_article">
  <div class="article_title">{{article.title}}</div>
  <div class="article_text">{{article.summary | slice:0:100}}...</div>
</div>
```

article.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";
import {map, Observable, tap} from "rxjs";
import {ArticleModel} from "../model/articleModel";

@Injectable({
   providedIn: 'root'
})

export class ArticleService {

   private url = 'https://api.spaceflightnewsapi.net/v3/'
   constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

   getArticles():Observable<ArticleModel[]> {
      return this.httpClient.get<ArticleModel[]>(this.url + 'blogs?_limit=75');
   }

   findArticlesByNameAndContent(title: string, summary: string):Observable<ArticleModel[]> {
     return this.httpClient.get<ArticleModel[]>(this.url + 'blogs?_limit=75').pipe(
    tap(x => console.log(x)),
    map(articles => articles.filter(article => article.title.includes(title) || article.summary.includes(summary))));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is here:

```
searchArticle() {
  this.articleService.findArticlesByNameAndContent(this.searchArticlesForm.value, this.searchArticlesForm.value)
    .subscribe(value => this.articles = value);
}
```

Remember that `formGroup.value` returns an object with the key/value pairs of the formControls and you are expecting `string` parameters in your method.

If you change this call

```
  findArticlesByNameAndContent(this.searchArticlesForm.value, this.searchArticlesForm.value)
```

for this one

```
  findArticlesByNameAndContent(this.searchArticlesForm.value.article, this.searchArticlesForm.value.article)
```

should work.

```
   ngOnInit(): void {
     this.articleService.getArticles().subscribe(value => this.articles = value);
     this.searchArticlesForm.valueChanges.subscribe(() => {
      this.searchArticle();
     });
   }
```

This is a quick solution, of course can be improved!

Comment: Thank you very much, is works) But i have two more questions. When i typing nothing happens, but when i typed the text and pressed enter it showing the lists. Is it possible to do it without pressing `enter`? And how to filter elements that the article with one match in the name is higher than the article with one match in the description? Please, help me with it. Thank you

Comment: Dont use `(change)` event in your form. Use instead `valueChanges` Observable. Im going to add an example to the answer.

Comment: By the way, this is a recomendation of the Oficial Docs.

Comment: Thank you, i am waiting for your answer)

Comment: Note that this going to search every time the input value change. Consider to put a debounce time and a loading spinner to notify the user that you are performing a search.

Comment: Thank you, is works fine) I have the last quesiton, sorry me that a big count of question. How to show the lenght of results during the finding?

Comment: Did you mean this `<div>{{ articles.length }}</div>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244769/discussion-between-defender-and-cybering).